# How to get base64 string from img element in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, base64

I have an image element that displays an image from URL. How can I get this image data (not URL) as a base64 string in Angular 7?

I didn't find any solution for my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266377/11343720

Comment: thank you, but this is js code. How can I convert it to ts?

Comment: Why my question is downvoted? (Just to know)

Comment: We can use any javascript code in angular 7

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.html:**

```
<img id="imgElement" src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0'>
<button (click)="onTap()">Get base 64</button>

<div>
    <b>Base64: </b>
    {{base64}}
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  base64;
  onTap(): void {
    var self = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
        self.base64 = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    var img: any = document.getElementById('imgElement');
    xhr.open('GET', img.src);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
  }
  title = 'base64-ng7';

}
```

**Full Source code:**
https://nkhs:bgt123123@github.com/nkhs/base64-ng7.git

**Reference:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/11343720